# UI5 JS update table by button

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I'm new to UI5 and JS and trying to practice development of UI5 apps in WebIDE.

In this scenario I made in XML view a table which is populated by JSON module. There are few inputs with button. I would like to add values entered to fields to table (and also update that JSON module). 
Thank you for any guidance or help.

I got error on line - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
var newBp = oModel.getProperty("/hosesMbh");

Jan

```
sap.ui.controller("com.sapx05.view.View1", {
onInit: function() {
    var oData = {
        "hosesMbh": [{
            "orderNumber": "1275043",
            "materialNumber": "6460000214",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275044",
            "materialNumber": "6442041132",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275083",
            "materialNumber": "6460000219",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275088",
            "materialNumber": "6460000229",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275089",
            "materialNumber": "6460000239",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }]
    };
    var JSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
    JSONModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(JSONModel);

    var XMLModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
        $.get("data.xml", function(data) {
            XMLModel.setXML(data);
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(XMLModel,"xml");
         }, "text");
},

onBtnClickAdd: function(oData, JSONModel) {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData("/hosesMbh");
    var newBp = oModel.getProperty("/hosesMbh");
    var addOrder = {
            orderNumberAdd: this.getView().byId("orderNumberAdd").getValue(),
            materialNumberAdd: this.getView().byId("materialNumberAdd").getValue(),
            amountOrderedAdd: this.getView().byId("amountOrderedAdd").getValue(),
            amountProducedAdd: this.getView().byId("amountProducedAdd").getValue(),
            openAmountAdd: this.getView().byId("openAmountAdd").getValue()
    };
    newBp.push(addOrder);
    JSONModel.setProperty("/hosesMbh", newBp);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new JSON model in your `onBtnClickAdd` mehtod without any data in it. Therefore this model does not contain the property `/hosesMbh`. Instead you should get the model from the core, which you create in the `onInit` method.

```
onBtnClickAdd: function(oData, JSONModel) {
    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
    oModel.loadData("/hosesMbh");
    var newBp = oModel.getProperty("/hosesMbh");
    var addOrder = {
        orderNumberAdd: this.getView().byId("orderNumberAdd").getValue(),
        materialNumberAdd: this.getView().byId("materialNumberAdd").getValue(),
        amountOrderedAdd: this.getView().byId("amountOrderedAdd").getValue(),
        amountProducedAdd: this.getView().byId("amountProducedAdd").getValue(),
        openAmountAdd: this.getView().byId("openAmountAdd").getValue()
    };
    newBp.push(addOrder);
    oModel.setProperty("/hosesMbh", newBp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working fine. Could you also guide me how to update that table content with updated module?

Comment: Fixed an issue in my code. When the JSON model is bound to the table with `oTable.bindRows("/hosesMbh")`, the table should be updated automatically after calling `oModel.setProperty("/hosesMbh", newBp);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, first answer helped me with passing through error with 
`newBp.push(addOrder);`

but still changed model (oModel)`oModel.setProperty("/hosesMbh", newBp);`
does not place 6th line (from fields) to table. I think that active model still remains that JSONModel created during oninit.

Note: comparing to first post, I added second table.

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
"sap/ui/table/Table",
"sap/m/Label",
"sap/m/Input"], 
function(Controller,Table,Label,Input) {
"use strict";
return Controller.extend("com.sapx05.view.View1", {
onInit: function() {
    var oData = {
        "hosesMbh": [{
            "orderNumber": "1275043",
            "materialNumber": "6460000214",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275044",
            "materialNumber": "6442041132",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275083",
            "materialNumber": "6460000219",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275088",
            "materialNumber": "6460000229",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }, {
            "orderNumber": "1275089",
            "materialNumber": "6460000239",
            "amountOrdered": "640m",
            "amountProduced": "200m",
            "openAmount": "440m"
        }]};
var JSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
JSONModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay);
this.getView().setModel(JSONModel);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(JSONModel);

var XMLModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
$.get("data.xml", function(data) {
XMLModel.setXML(data);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(XMLModel,"xml");
}, "text");
},
onBtnClickAdd: function(oData,JSONModel) {
// user table - newly created by button click
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    title : "Table 2",
    width : "100%",
    visibleRowCount : 7
});
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Order number"}),
    template: new sap.m.Input({value:"{orderNumber}"})
}));
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Material number"}),
    template: new sap.m.Input({value:"{materialNumber}"})
}));
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Amount Ordered"}),
    template: new sap.m.Input({value:"{amountOrdered}"})
}));
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Amount produced"}),
    template: new sap.m.Input({value:"{amountProduced}"})
}));
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Open amount"}),
    template: new sap.m.Input({value:"{openAmount}"})
}));
oTable.bindRows("/hosesMbh");
oTable.placeAt("content");
//table is created and populated
//fields for values to be added
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel(JSONModel);
    oModel.loadData("/hosesMbh");
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

var newBp = oModel.getProperty("/hosesMbh");

this.getView().byId("orderNumberAdd").setValue("12345");
this.getView().byId("materialNumberAdd").setValue("6460000223");
this.getView().byId("amountOrderedAdd").setValue("640m");
this.getView().byId("amountProducedAdd").setValue("440m");
this.getView().byId("openAmountAdd").setValue("200m");

var addOrder = {
            orderNumberAdd: this.getView().byId("orderNumberAdd").getValue(),
            materialNumberAdd: this.getView().byId("materialNumberAdd").getValue(),
            amountOrderedAdd: this.getView().byId("amountOrderedAdd").getValue(),
            amountProducedAdd: this.getView().byId("amountProducedAdd").getValue(),
            openAmountAdd: this.getView().byId("openAmountAdd").getValue()
        };
    newBp.push(addOrder);
//newBp contains 5 lines of original /hosesMbh content and also 6th line from fields    
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
    oModel.setProperty("/hosesMbh", newBp);
//model is updated i guess (no error occured in chrome debugger) 
//but content of tables they have bound rows to /hosesMbh was not changed
}
});});
```